# Xamarin Forms: Disable stretching in webview while scrolling (IOS)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

is it possible to deactivated this stetching animation which you can see when you scroll up or down at the start or the end of an website in a webview?

Here is one image of the problem: [image]

Thans for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default iOS behavior, you need to write a Custom Renderer for disabling it

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    ScrollView.Bounces = false;
}
```